# How to run the dashboard in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dashboard

I started to learn dashboards in Jupyter Notebook and faced the problem, i cannot launch it and visit the link that has been  created. I have searched some documentations, but did not find the answer, the code:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc

import dash_html_components as html

import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash()

app.Layout = html.Div(children = [html.H1("Hello")])

app.run_server()
```

after the last line is run, i have the following message:

```
Running on http://127.0.0.1:8050/
Debugger PIN: 872-718-697
 * Serving Flask app "__main__" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 1
```

if i visit the link from the first line in message, the page is not loading

Comment: Appears you're trying to run a Flask app from Jupyter. Jupyter uses Tornado webserver and widgets/dashboards/extensions in Jupyter are static Angular applications

Answer (score 0):

In the jupyterLab environment, by installing the module, the execution result will be displayed as a cell result. The installation instructions can be found [here](https://medium.com/plotly/introducing-jupyterdash-811f1f57c02e). jupyterlab is recommended.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash 
import pandas as pd

# app = dash.Dash()
app = JupyterDash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(children="Hello")])

app.run_server(mode='inline') # JupyterDash mode='inline'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `App.layout`, you are using upper case `app.Layout` but it must be `app.layout`, this code will work:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

import pandas as pd
    
app = dash.Dash()
    
app.layout = html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.H1(children='Hello Dash')
                    ]
                )
app.run_server()
```