# stuck in app.run_server() with jupyter dash

Tags: plotly-dash

I am using JupyterDash, recently I updated dash, then the run stuck at running server and it never finish when running the below code. I am using jupyter lab. Not sure why? so I have restart kernel each time and the issue is gone.  Thanks

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(mode='external',debug=True,port=8060)
```

Comment: It is hard to tell you why from this snippet of code, please add a full example to try it on our machine.

Comment: As Hamzah said, your post good use improving. However, if you are running those two lines you posted above to kick off a JupyterDash app and wondering why it keeps running, you aren't understanding what is going on. You may want to build up to that using other examples of running it in Jupyter notebook, such as [here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/65472830/8508004). Note that the code there doesn't have that line `f __name__ == "__main__":` and doesn't have `external` as mode. If you run what you run in a notebook, that cell would have to keep running to keep the app_server engaged. ...

Comment: <continued> Normally if you see `if __name__ == "__main__":`, it means you put it in text file and invoke it as a script. Let's say you named that script, `app_run.py`. You'd kick off your app running by typing **in a terminal** `python app_run.py`. And leave that terminal window active so your app server continues to run until you want to end it. Then in a URL you type the address it probably suggests and will involve port `8060` since you have `port=8060` in your `app_run.py`.

Comment: Thanks Wayne, the reason I didnt post my script was because the script is really big. I just removed if __name__ == "__main__", and the issue stays the same, it just keeps running.  It was fine before I made a dash upgrade recently. However, to solve this issue, I have to restart kernel and then run the cells.   Also, if I just run the cell with only app.run_server(mode='external',debug=True,port=8060)  , it didn't create the dash http link like:   Dash app running on http://127.0.0.1:8060/, not sure why? Thanks for your help. I appreciate it